# How do you generate random items from an array without repeating in React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, function

Below is a snippet of my code.. I'm working on a random quote generator and would like to find a solution on generating each random quote and background from the arrays without repeats until all have been used, and then cycling through again. The background images are being imported directly into the state and the quote array is imported from a separate file. I've attempted slicing each item from the array and pushing it into an empty one, but so far that has been unsuccessful.

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            quote: quotes[0].quote,
            author: quotes[0].author,
            backgrounds: [
                photos..
            ]
        };
    }
    
    
    shuffleAll = (arr) => {
        return arr.sort(function () { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
    }
    
    findRandomQuote = (arr) => {
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        let randQuote = quotes[num];
        this.shuffleAll(quotes);
        this.setState({
            quote: randQuote.quote,
            author: randQuote.author
        });
    }

    findRandomBackground = (arr) => {
        const { backgrounds } = this.state;
        let background = backgrounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * backgrounds.length)];
        this.shuffleAll(backgrounds);
        document.body.style.background = `url(${background})`;
    }
```

Comment: What is `quotes`? Please try creating a [mcve]

Comment: "I've attempted slicing each item from the array and pushing it into an empty one" - Please also share the code that you've attempted

Comment: quotes is being imported in from a separate file holding my quotes array, which has both the quote and author in each index. previously I have tried adding another item to state such as  usedQuotes = [ ] , and then after setting state I added quotes.slice(randQuote).push(this.usedQutoes) to the function findRandomQuote, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use state to store the quote array, and substract from it until all quotes are used up:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        availableQuotes: [...quotes],
        activeQuote: null
    };
}

findRandomQuote = () => {
    const quoteOptions = this.state.availableQuotes.length > 0 ? this.state.availableQuotes : quotes;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteOptions.length);
    this.setState({
        availableQuotes: [...quoteOptions].splice(randomIndex, 1),
        activeQuote: quoteOptions[randomIndex]
    });
}


// This runs after component mounts, to set the first random quote
componentDidMount() { 
    this.findRandomQuote();
}
```

You can do a similar thing to randomise the background images.

Comment: I haven't quite gotten this solution to work with my code, but adding componentDidMount fixed another issue I've had with rendering the first random quote on page load, so thank you!!